# How i can check with preg_match contain my string any digits or not?

Tags: php, preg-match

I need to check in a string of digits, ie all other characters such as ~; & * ^ # & ^ Should not fall under check. I need it to form validation. Now i use that construction:

```
return ( ! preg_match("/^([0-9])+$/i", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
```

I have a form for edeiting firstname and lastname of users. Also when someone try to add name with characters somth like that: "kickman!@#$%^&*())))(*&^%$##$%" my form should complete validation without errors. But if i have there any digit i should get an error, somth like : "123kickman!@#$%^&*())))(*&^%$##$%".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (!preg_match("#^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$#", $text)){
   echo 'String also contains other characters.';  
} else {
   echo 'String only contains numbers and letters.';
}
```

or this:

```
function countDigits($str)
{
    return preg_match_all( "/[0-9]/", $str );
}
```

Comment: Also it didnt fine for me, cos i need all characters and letters but i no need digits.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: return ( preg_match_all("/[0-9]/", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE; That variant works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to see if all characters are digits, just create a function and pass the string to it:

```
$x = match("01234");
echo $x."<br>";
$x = match("0$#21234");
echo $x."<br>";
function match($str)
{
return ( ! preg_match("/^([0-9])+$/i", $str)) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

**Edit according to question update:**

```
if (preg_match('/\d/', $string)) {
    echo "KO, at least one digit\n";
} else {
    echo "OK, no digits found\n";
}
```

Or, in a function:

```
return !preg_match('/d/', $string);
```

Comment: i try before with \d but dunno why it didnt work. Also i no need check all characters are digits or not. I need check if any character in that string is digit.

Comment: @kickman2l: It isn't clear what is your needs. Please, edit your question and give some sample strings and the expected result for each ones.

Comment: Edit my question. Sry my bad english.